# why custom validator is triggered before ngModel value is changed?

Tags: angular, angular-custom-validators

I have added a custom validator for a checkbox that is data bound using `ngModel`. I observed that the custom validator function is trigerred before the `ngModel` bound value is changed.

I have checked the value of my `ngModel` bound variable using breakpoint and it is still not updated and custom validator function is executed before update.

I am new to Angular, can anyone tell me why custom validator function is executed before the bound variable is set on unchecking the checkbox, yielding  unexpected results.

Comment: Use custom validator in ``ngOnInit()`` life cycle hook and ``ngModel`` in the ``constructor``

Comment: I can't do that because I'm updating the array with the elements which are unchecked so I have to use ngModel variable in change event of checkbox

Comment: I am not able to post code because of validation of code field by stack overflow:(. I wish code format validation should be removed by stack overflow.